# Cannot install Xcode on a Mac OS X Mavericks virtual machine

Tags: xcode, macos, virtualbox

I am running a Niresh VirtualBox machine with OS X Mavericks. When I try to install Xcode 5, it gives me an error:

> **We could not complete your purchase.**
>
> There is not enough disk space available to install "TITLE".

My virtual machine actually has a 100GB dynamic virtual hard disk. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem..you should re-install your maverick os,be-careful while configuring your virtual image size and your actual HD space is available(free)..